# What is the apt Oracle data type to store ISOYearMonth?

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I searched for suitable Oracle data type to store ISOYearMonth.  But come across Date, TimeStamp data types to store Date with time with precision variations. Please guide me in selecting apt Oracle data type to store ISOYearMonth.

Comment: What is the contents of that field? Would a numeric be the logical choice?

Answer (score 0):

I think use `DATE` type will be most suitable.

You will need truncate dates using `TRUNC(my_date, 'MONTH')`  when you will insert data into table. 
In this case you don't need any additional conversion when you will select data for comparisons or arithmetic operations

Of course, if you want to see this date on the screen in ISOYearMonth format, you should convert data to string using `TO_CHAR(my_date, 'YYYY-MM')` in your query.